# 404 error for Shared Access Signature with v2 of Azure Storage Client Library

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to generate a Shared Access Signature for a blob (and use it) **with the v2.0** of the Windows Azure Storage Client Library.
I started with [this sample](http://vunvulearadu.blogspot.ro/2012/07/how-to-use-shared-access-signature-with.html) but it's for v1.7, and transposing it to 2.0 gives a 404 error.

Here is my actual code :
Server side, to generate the SAS :

```
var myAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
                              "AzureStorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
var myContainer = myAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
                                          .GetContainerReference(containerName);
myContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

string blobName = "Imports/" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") 
                             + ".zip";
var myBlob = myContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
using (var stream = 
 new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hey, I'm empty for now.")))
{
    myBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);
}

var sharedAccesSignature = myBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(
                 new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
{
   Permissions = 
       Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write 
       | Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
       SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
});

return myBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sharedAccesSignature;
```

It tried many things at client side, resulting sometimes in 404, or 403 server error.
For exemple I tried this (result : 404) :

```
var blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(new Uri(blobWithSharedAccessSignature));
// blobWithSharedAccessSignature here is : https://azertyuiop.blob.core.windows.net/container1/Imports/2012-12-01_19-43-54.zip?sv=2012-02-12&se=2012-12-01T20%3A43%3A54Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sig=h0bTUk[...]3D
// calling blobWithSharedAccessSignature from a webBrowser works.
// result here is valid for containerName : container1
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
ICloudBlob blobRef = container.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(blobWithSharedAccessSignature);   ==> error 404
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileFullPath))
{
    blobRef.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

I tried replacing

```
container.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(blobWithSharedAccessSignature);
```

by

```
container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobWithSharedAccessSignature);
```

I also tried replacing

```
blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(new Uri(blobWithSharedAccessSignature));
```

by

```
blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(new Uri(blobWithSharedAccessSignature), new StorageCredentials(blobWithSharedAccessSignature));
```

which results in a "403 - forbidden" error.

Can someone help me by giving a full sample in v2 ? Or tell me were's my mistake ? Thanks !

**UPDATE - solution here :** (thanks to Sandrino Di Mattia)

```
// Assuming that blobWithSharedAccessSignature is : 
//  "https://azertyuiop.blob.core.windows.net/container1/Imports/2012-12-01_19-43-54.zip?sv=2012-02-12&se=2012-12-01T20%3A43%3A54Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sig=h0bTUkTR%2FdTF%2BVZgDUuBPHqG%2BiTtFeXK4kepBpDR2AU%3D"
Uri blobUriWithoutCredentials = new Uri(new Uri(blobWithSharedAccessSignature).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));
// here blobUriWithoutCredentials is https://azertyuiop.blob.core.windows.net/container1/Imports/2012-12-01_19-43-54.zip
string credentials = blobWithSharedAccessSignature.Substring(blobWithSharedAccessSignature.IndexOf('?'));
// here credentials is "?sv=2012-02-12&se=2012-12-01T22%3A26%3A55Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sig=Lsk8kLyJ8TFoGNVLbFLftCIXUNlIIRPZalkhoPdUfh8%3D"
var blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(blobUriWithoutCredentials, new StorageCredentials(credentials));
ICloudBlob blobRef = blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(blobUriWithoutCredentials);
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileFullPath))
{
    blobRef.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: i need your help in this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847102/upload-file-with-azure-storage-using-sas-shared-access-signature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When initializing the `CloudBlobClient` you need to pass 2 parameters

- **baseUri**: Blob url without SAS, `http://test.blob.core.windows.net/temp/Imports/2012-12-01_20-56-52.zip`
- **credentials**: This should be your SAS without the url, `?sv=2012-02-12&se=2012-12-01T21%3A57%3A56Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sig=5JboXXM1Yeo%2BuI6mb18VbURluo%3D`

Working sample:

```
var blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(new Uri(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri), new StorageCredentials(sharedAccesSignature));
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileFullPath))
{

    blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(new Uri(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri))
                .UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

Extra tip: You don't need to get a reference to the container. You can immediately access the blob by calling `GetBlobReferenceFromServer` on the `CloudBlobClient`.

Comment: It works, thanks ! But I don't understand the logic at all : why the CloudBlobClient isn't able to find itself the credentials and the base Uri from only one single URI ? It's quite strange ! It's just 2 lines of code (see my edit with the final solution).
BTW, thank you very much for your answer !

Comment: This was probably done to decouple the authentication from the actual Blob Service implementation. The result is that your code can be the same for SAS requests and "full access" requests (account name+key) by simply providing a different `StorageCredentials`.

Comment: I am not sure whether you can help me or not, can you please look at this question and reply me there..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847102/upload-file-with-azure-storage-using-sas-shared-access-signature

Comment: In My platform (Android) I am not getting method that is similar to GetBlobReferenceFromServer. In that case what should i do?