# How to create Container and upload Data with only SAS with AzureBlobStorage Java SDK v10

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

I got, from my college, a SAS Token. The SAS Token looks like this one here:

https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2015-04-05&st=2015-04-29T22%3A18%3A26Z&se=2015-04-30T02%3A23%3A26Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sip=168.1.5.60-168.1.5.70&spr=https&sig=Z%2FRHIX5Xcg0Mq2rqI3OlWTjEg2tYkboXr1P9ZUXDtkk%3D

He said that i can use it for creating containers and push data into this containers. So i began to code with some help of examples. I came up with this:

```
public ContainerURL getContainerURL() throws MalformedURLException {

    // From the Azure portal, get your Storage account's name and account key.
    String storgeResourceUri = "https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net";
    String sasToken = "https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2015-04-05&st=2015-04-29T22%3A18%3A26Z&se=2015-04-30T02%3A23%3A26Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sip=168.1.5.60-168.1.5.70&spr=https&sig=Z%2FRHIX5Xcg0Mq2rqI3OlWTjEg2tYkboXr1P9ZUXDtkk%3D";

    StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature creds = new StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature(sasToken);


    // Create a ServiceURL objet that wraps the service URL and a request pipeline.
    ServiceURL serviceURL = new ServiceURL(new URL(storgeResourceUri), StorageURL.createPipeline(creds, new PipelineOptions()));

    // Now you can use the ServiceURL to perform various container and blob operations.

    // This example shows several common operations just to get you started.

    /*
    Create a URL that references a to-be-created container in your Azure Storage account. This returns a
    ContainerURL object that wraps the container's URL and a request pipeline (inherited from serviceURL).
    Note that container names require lowercase.
     */

    return serviceURL.createContainerURL("mapupdate-container");
}

public void uploadFile(ContainerURL containerURL, File sourceFile) throws IOException {

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());

    File zippedFile = zipping(sourceFile, timeStamp);

    BlockBlobURL blobURL = containerURL.createBlockBlobURL(zippedFile.getName());

    AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(zippedFile.toPath());

    // Uploading a file to the blobURL using the high-level methods available in TransferManager class
    // Alternatively call the Upload/StageBlock low-level methods from BlockBlobURL type
    TransferManager.uploadFileToBlockBlob(fileChannel, blobURL, (int) zippedFile.length(), null)
            .subscribe(response -> {
                System.out.println("Completed upload request.");
                System.out.println(response.response().statusCode());
            });
}
```

It should create a container with the name "mapudpater-container" and than upload a zipped file. Afterwards i want to send it via mqtt that another client can downlaod it with the link.

I not sure how to access the Azure Blob Storage account withe the SAS Token and  create the container and upload files into container. Should i create for each file i got a new container? How can i get an Link to download from it? Do i have to create my own SAS Token to download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SAS as the credentials for your connection string. The connection string format is (line breaks included for readability only):

```html
BlobEndpoint=myBlobEndpoint;
QueueEndpoint=myQueueEndpoint;
TableEndpoint=myTableEndpoint;
FileEndpoint=myFileEndpoint;
SharedAccessSignature=sasToken
```

[azure-storage-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/Samples.java)

Please see [Create a connection string using a shared access signature for more information and examples.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string#create-a-connection-string-using-a-shared-access-signature)

For more information, you may also refer to the suggestions mentioned in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847102/upload-file-with-azure-storage-using-sas-shared-access-signature) thread.

[Uploading to Azure Blob Storage with Shared Access Signatures](https://markheath.net/post/upload-azure-blob-storage-sas)

In this how-to guide, you learn [how to use the client library for Java  to upload, download, and list block blobs in a container in Azure Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java).

The following are [Java code examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob&method=upload) for showing how to use upload() of the [com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlobclass.](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob)

Additional information:
This topic shows sample uses of [shared access signatures with the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/service-sas-examples). Shared access signatures permit you to provide access rights to containers and blobs, tables, queues, or files.

Comment: You said "Shared access signatures permit you to provide access rights to containers and blobs, tables, queues, or files." But i can not create my own containers, blobs, tables, queeus or files with only SAS? I need Accountname and Accountkey?

Comment: which type of SAS did you try? If it's a account sas: It should work, If the issue persists  can you provide details what all the steps you have performed 

If you are using Service sas: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#types-of-shared-access-signatures the doc clarifies account sas can be used to manage container

Comment: I could solve the problem. Now i want to upload a file into a container but i get an Exception. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790789/error-while-uploding-blob-with-transfermanager-azure-blob-storage)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to interact with AzureBlobStorage and manage file using Java,

1. Azure Storage Blob - It uses the REST based mechanism to connect with Azure Storage Blob and manage the files. It is relatively slow.

   ```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Azure Storage - It is Cloud API provided by Azure and it is faster than the REST based API

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
       <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
       <version>8.6.4</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Below the utility has been created for both type of implementation:

```
  import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.URISyntaxException;
  import java.net.URL;
  import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
  import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
  import java.util.Calendar;
  import java.util.EnumSet;
  import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
  import java.util.Locale;
  import java.util.Objects;
  import java.util.TimeZone;
  
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlockBlobURL;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobClient;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.ContainerURL;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.DownloadResponse;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.PipelineOptions;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.ServiceURL;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.SharedAccessBlobPermissions;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.SharedAccessBlobPolicy;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.SharedKeyCredentials;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.StorageURL;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobDeleteResponse;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.models.BlockBlobUploadResponse;
  import com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Base64;
  import com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.HttpPipeline;
  import com.microsoft.rest.v2.util.FlowableUtil;
  
  import io.reactivex.Flowable;
  import io.reactivex.Single;

  public class AzureStorageUtils {

public static void main(String...args) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.pdf");
    int available = fis.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[available];
    fis.read(buffer);
    fis.close();
    
    String accountName = "enter azure account name";
    String accountKey = "enter account key ";
    
    BlobFile file = new BlobFile();
    file.setFileType("image");
    file.setFileName("directory1/image.pdf");
    file.setFileSize(available);
    file.setContent(buffer);
    
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    uploadFile(accountName, accountKey, file);
    //deleteFile(accountName, accountKey, file);
    
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Start Time: " + startTime);
    System.out.println("End Time: " + endTime);
    System.out.println("Time Taken: " + (endTime - startTime));
    
    
    String connectionString = "entery connection string for azure blob";

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    create(connectionString, "image", "directory1/image.pdf", buffer);
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Start Time: " + startTime);
    System.out.println("End Time: " + endTime);
    System.out.println("Time Taken: " + (endTime - startTime));

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    byte[] temp = read(connectionString, "image", "directory1/image.pdf");
    System.out.println(Base64.encode(temp));
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Start Time: " + startTime);
    System.out.println("End Time: " + endTime);
    System.out.println("Time Taken: " + (endTime - startTime));

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String sasURL = sasURL(connectionString, "image", "directory1/image.pdf");
    System.out.println(sasURL);
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Start Time: " + startTime);
    System.out.println("End Time: " + endTime);
    System.out.println("Time Taken: " + (endTime - startTime));
    
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    delete(connectionString, "image", "directory1/image.pdf");
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Start Time: " + startTime);
    System.out.println("End Time: " + endTime);
    System.out.println("Time Taken: " + (endTime - startTime));
}


/**
* azure-storage
*/
private static CloudBlobClient createCloudBlobClient(String connectionString) throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException {
    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString);
    return account.createCloudBlobClient();
}

private static CloudBlobContainer getBlobConatiner(String connectionString, String containerName) throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException {
    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = createCloudBlobClient(connectionString);
    CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);
    cloudBlobContainer.createIfNotExists();
    return cloudBlobContainer;
}

public static CloudBlockBlob create(String connectionString, String containerName, String filePath, byte[] data) throws RuntimeException {
    try {
        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = getBlobConatiner(connectionString, containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.getBlockBlobReference(filePath);
        cloudBlockBlob.uploadFromByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        return cloudBlockBlob;
    }
    catch(InvalidKeyException | URISyntaxException | StorageException | IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

public static byte[] read(String connectionString, String containerName, String filePath) throws RuntimeException {
    try {
        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = getBlobConatiner(connectionString, containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.getBlockBlobReference(filePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        cloudBlockBlob.download(outputStream);
        byte[] byteArray =  outputStream.toByteArray();
        outputStream.close();
        return byteArray;
    }
    catch(InvalidKeyException | URISyntaxException | StorageException | IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

public static boolean delete(String connectionString, String containerName, String filePath) throws RuntimeException {
    try {
        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = getBlobConatiner(connectionString, containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.getBlockBlobReference(filePath);
        return cloudBlockBlob.deleteIfExists();
    }
    catch(InvalidKeyException | URISyntaxException | StorageException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

public static String sasURL(String connectionString, String containerName, String filePath) throws RuntimeException {
    try {
        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = getBlobConatiner(connectionString, containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.getBlockBlobReference(filePath);
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
        sasPolicy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(calendar.getTime());
        sasPolicy.setPermissions(EnumSet.of(SharedAccessBlobPermissions.READ, SharedAccessBlobPermissions.WRITE, SharedAccessBlobPermissions.LIST));
        String sas = cloudBlockBlob.generateSharedAccessSignature(sasPolicy,null);
        return cloudBlockBlob.getUri()+"?"+sas;
    }
    catch(InvalidKeyException | URISyntaxException | StorageException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}



/**
* azure-storage-blob
*/
private static BlockBlobURL getBlobURL(String accountName, String accountKey, String containerName, String filename) throws Exception {
    ContainerURL containerURL = null;
    BlockBlobURL blobURL = null;
    try {
        SharedKeyCredentials credential = new SharedKeyCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        HttpPipeline pipeline = StorageURL.createPipeline(credential, new PipelineOptions());
        URL url = new URL(String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.blob.core.windows.net", accountName));
        ServiceURL serviceURL = new ServiceURL(url, pipeline);
        containerURL = serviceURL.createContainerURL(containerName);
        blobURL = containerURL.createBlockBlobURL(filename);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
    return blobURL;
}   

public static boolean uploadFile(String accountName, String accountKey, BlobFile file) throws Exception {
    boolean isUploaded = false;
    if (Objects.isNull(file.getFileType())) {
        throw new Exception("FileType is missing");
    }
    if (Objects.isNull(file.getFileName())) {
        throw new Exception("FileName is missing");
    }
    if (Objects.isNull(file.getContent())) {
        throw new Exception("Content is missing");
    }
    if (file.getFileSize() == 0) {
        throw new Exception("File's size is missing");
    }

    BlockBlobURL blobURL = getBlobURL(accountName, accountKey, file.getFileType(), file.getFileName());
    Single<BlockBlobUploadResponse> blobResponse = blobURL.upload(Flowable.just(ByteBuffer.wrap(file.getContent())), file.getFileSize(), null, null, null, null);
    if (blobResponse.blockingGet().statusCode() == 201) {
        isUploaded = true;
    }
    return isUploaded;
}

public static BlobFile downloadFile(String accountName, String accountKey, BlobFile file) throws Exception {
    if (Objects.isNull(file.getFileType())) {
        throw new Exception("FileType is missing");
    }
    if (Objects.isNull(file.getFileName())) {
        throw new Exception("FileName is missing");
    }
    BlockBlobURL blobURL = getBlobURL(accountName, accountKey, file.getFileType(), file.getFileName());
    Single<DownloadResponse> blobResponse = blobURL.download(null, null, false, null);
    Flowable<ByteBuffer> fByteBuffer = blobResponse.blockingGet().body(null);
    Single<ByteBuffer> bf = FlowableUtil.collectBytesInBuffer(fByteBuffer);
    file.setContent(bf.blockingGet().array());
    return file;
}

public static boolean deleteFile(String accountName, String accountKey, BlobFile file) throws Exception {
    boolean flag = false;
    if (Objects.isNull(file.getFileType())) {
        throw new Exception("FileType is missing");
    }
    if (Objects.isNull(file.getFileName())) {
        throw new Exception("FileName is missing");
    }
    BlockBlobURL blobURL = getBlobURL(accountName, accountKey, file.getFileType(), file.getFileName());
    Single<BlobDeleteResponse> blobResponse = blobURL.delete(null, null, null);
    if (blobResponse.blockingGet().statusCode() == 201) {
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}   

  }
```

The above solution has both implementation, also we have compared the time taken for same activity like upload for same file.

The preferred approach is to use azure-storage dependency.